# Java constructors assingning value to variable and then interchanging them

Tags: java

What should be the output of the following code and why?
The output turned out to be 131713. Below is the code. The object references are interchanging so the values are changing.

```
public class Test { 
    int age;
    String name;

    Test(int age,String name) {
        this.age=age;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Test t1 = new Test(17,"A");
        Test t2 = new Test(13,"B");
        Test t3 = new Test(14,"C");
        t3=t2;
        t2=t1;
        t1=t3;
        System.out.print(t1.age);
        System.out.print(t2.age);
        System.out.print(t3.age);
    }    
}
```

Comment: You know what the output is, so you're just asking why? Why do you think? What do you think it should be? Why?

Comment: By the time you get to the assignment into `t1`, what value does `t3` have?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the value of a reference variable doesn't modify anything inside the object that it refers to.  But it can make that variable refer to a different object.  The variables exist independently of the objects.  This can be visualised as in the following diagrams.

After you create your three objects, you have a situation like this.

```
      /       \        /       \        /       \
      |       |        |       |        |       |
 t1-> | 17  A |   t2-> | 13  B |   t3-> | 14  C |     
      |       |        |       |        |       |
      \       /        \       /        \       /
```

Then you change what t3 refers to, so you have

```
      /       \        /       \        /       \
      |       |   t2-> |       |        |       |
 t1-> | 17  A |        | 13  B |        | 14  C |     
      |       |   t3-> |       |        |       |
      \       /        \       /        \       /
```

Then you change what t2 refers to, so you have

```
      /       \        /       \        /       \
 t1-> |       |        |       |        |       |
      | 17  A |   t3-> | 13  B |        | 14  C |     
 t2-> |       |        |       |        |       |
      \       /        \       /        \       /
```

And you change what t1 refers to, so you have

```
      /       \        /       \        /       \
      |       |   t1-> |       |        |       |
 t2-> | 17  A |        | 13  B |        | 14  C |     
      |       |   t3-> |       |        |       |
      \       /        \       /        \       /
```

Then you start printing stuff.  As shown in the final diagram above,  `t1.age` and `t3.age` are both `13`, and `t2.age` is `17`.